# Neural Network - TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm having problem with neural network that I want to create using numpy and pandas as my dependencies. Network should to predict the magnitude of an Earthquake given the date, time, Latitude, and Longitude as features. Here's snippet from dataset:

```
Date    Time    Latitude    Longitude   Magnitude
0   01/02/1965  13:44:18    19.246  145.616 6.0
1   01/04/1965  11:29:49    1.863   127.352 5.8
2   01/05/1965  18:05:58    -20.579 -173.972    6.2
3   01/08/1965  18:49:43    -59.076 -23.557 5.8
4   01/09/1965  13:32:50    11.938  126.427 5.8
```

And here's code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Kamalov/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/my_code/datasets/database.csv")
train, test = data[:15000], data[15000:]
trainX, trainY = train[["Date","Time","Latitude","Longitude"]], train['Magnitude']
testX, testY = test[["Date","Time","Latitude","Longitude"]], test['Magnitude']

def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return output

def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

synapse_0 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
synapse_1 = 2*np.random.random((1,4)) - 1

X = trainX.values
y = trainY.values


for iter in range(50000):
    # forward propagation
    layer_0 = X
    layer_1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_0,synapse_0))

    layer_2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer_1,synapse_1))

    # how much did we miss?
    layer_2_error = layer_2 - y

    # multiply how much we missed by the 
    # slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
    layer_2_delta = layer_2_error * sigmoid_output_to_derivative(layer_2)
    synapse_0_derivative = np.dot(layer_0.T,layer_2_delta)

    # update weights
    synapse_0 -= synapse_0_derivative

print ("Output After Training:")
print (layer_2)
```

I'm getting

> "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

error, even though I converted my dataframe to numpy array.

Any help is appreciated :/

Comment: The error probably tells you exactly where in your code it occurs. Why hide this from us? Furthermore that's a common python-error and googling will tell you in which cases this one will occur. Combining these two hints should help you to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The error message may be a bit misleading. It is caused because your DataFrame contains columns of dtype `object`, in your case the Date and Time columns. Converting to a numpy `ndarray` doesn't help much as the data type will not change. You need to convert these columns to int or float values before you can use `np.dot()`.